# Legacy Xorg fonts.alias matching does not work anymore

Tags: xorg, xfig

I have

```
# xset -q
[...]
Font-Path:
   /usr/share/fonts/misc/,/usr/share/fonts/TTF/,/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/,built-ins
[...]
```

and for example a /usr/share/fonts/misc/fonts.alias, that defines "fixed":

```
(cd /usr/share/fonts; grep '^fixed' */fonts.alias)
cyrillic/fonts.alias
misc/fonts.alias
```

and I though that the fonts.alias would match for fontnames:

```
# xlsfonts -fn fixed
-misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-iso8859-1
fixed
```

(though the encoding iso8859-1 isn't even listed in any fonts.dir), actually

```
# grep '^fixed' */fonts.alias     # in /usr/share/fonts
misc/fonts.alias:fixed        -misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-iso8859-1
```

that seems the right match, but

```
# grep '^7x13bold' */fonts.alias
misc/fonts.alias:7x13bold     -misc-fixed-bold-r-normal--13-120-75-75-c-70-iso8859-1
```

I get

```
# xlsfonts -fn 7x13bold
xlsfonts: pattern "7x13bold" unmatched
```

and

```
# xfig
Warning: Cannot convert string "7x13bold" to type FontStruct
```

so as far as I used to understand it, the XServer **should** match against fonts.alias, but doesn't.

How does the Xorg Server matches fixed otherwise and fails to match 7x13bold or any other short form?

*Please don't tell me about fontconfig. I know fontconfig and how to use it, but that does **not** help with legacy XLoadFont operation that XFig uses, for example.*

May I need a xfontserver? I can't even see a gentoo package for the old xfs, possible because of security issues. Any further ideas welcome!

Comment: It seems that modern Xorg installation just support XLFD. Maybe we should fix the defaults for legacy programs like xfig.

Comment: I found the(?) solution. fonts.alias is not encoding agnostic. The encoding has to match the XLFD in the _auto-generated_ fonts.dir. I don't know yet why the XServer is able to map "`fixed`", though the alias was wrong too. BUT: You can simply edit (reduce) the fonts.alias to match the fonts.dir and do a `xset -fp PATH; xset +fp PATH` to make the XServer re-read the aliases. Now the aliases work again. So actually this should be fixed from within the font package of the distribution.